# Autoloading two vendor projects with composer at the same time

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-0

I've two projects (project1, project2) with composer set up correctly, with their own **composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "wp-cli/wp-cli": "0.15.1"
    }
}
```

Now, in another php file I autoload them via

```
require_once 'project1/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'project2/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And I get the error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare cli\render() (previously declared in 
/private/tmp/php/project1/vendor/wp-cli/php-cli-tools/lib/cli/cli.php:26)
in /private/tmp/php/project2/vendor/wp-cli/php-cli-tools/lib/cli/cli.php 
on line 28
```

Is it the problem of wp-cli or the issue with composer? I've tried with another library such as monolog which is fine.

Any idea?

Comment: You're redeclaring the same classes because you're including them twice (on both projects) why do you need the wp-cli twice?

Comment: Because I need to reference two projects' codes are the same time, and both of them already used wp-cli. I am just wondering why autoload can't help, because other library such as  monolog is okay even I autoload for the 2nd times.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use the Composer autoloader twice.

There is a simple solution: In your third project, create a new `composer.json` and include the two other projects there.

Then only include the autoloading of that third project. There will be no duplicate classes involved. This should work if you configured the correct autoloading not only for the libraries you use in any of the two projects, but also for all the classes in these projects.

Comment: I can't. Actually my suitation is to use composer in WordPress plugins, and they should don't know the existence of other plugins. So in each plugin, when they are being activated, they should load their own `autoload.php` and take care of their own dependency. My code above just simulate the case when two plugins with the same dependency are enabled.

Comment: Well, then you have a problem. If plugin 1 needs to use the same package as plugin 2, but in a different version, then you will create all kinds of undebuggable problems if the required versions of that package are different for each plugin. Imagine the same class in two incompatible versions. Autoloading it works for each plugin individually because the correct version is present, but putting it together with a second plugin that contains a different version will break the first or the second plugin depending on which class gets loaded first.